# Uploading files: Setting the value of "name" to be the file name

Tags: html

I have created an upload form and want to keep track of the files that I have uploaded.

```
    <form action="http://localhost:5000/add_csv_to_db" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="csv_file" accept="*">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

I have control of both client/server and this is just for my own use.

Is there a way to set `name="csv_file"` to be the name of the file? I have 100+ files I need to upload and want to keep track of which ones I've uploaded.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no need for this. `multipart/form-data` includes the file-name in the MIME-part header.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer

```
if 'csv_file' not in request.files:
    return 'didnt work'
f = request.files['csv_file']
print(f.filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for this. `multipart/form-data` includes the file-name in the MIME-part header.

In ASP.NET, it's exposed via the `HttpPostedFileBase.FileName` property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.filename(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm using Flask on the server side. How would I access it?